# Why do I have duplicates in Geoflutterfire `within`query?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I query my database for items within a distance from the user's position as follows:

```dart
  /// Get a stream of nearby  ads.
  static Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>> getNearbyStream(
      {required Position center, required double radius}) {
    final geo = Geoflutterfire();
    final collectionReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(collectionName);

    final gfpCenter = GeoFirePoint(center.latitude, center.longitude);

    return geo
        .collection(collectionRef: collectionReference)
        .within(
            center: gfpCenter,
            radius: radius,
            field: 'position',
            strictMode: true);
  }
```

To my surprise, the results shows duplicates: each result is shown twice.

How it comes?